# Will the group that "adduser" creates always have the same name as the user created?

Tags: linux

The `adduser` command creates a new user, and also creates a new group and make this new group the primary group for the new user.

Based on my testing, the group created by `adduser` have the same name as he user created. But is this always the case, or are there some situations where the group will have a different name?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your systems configuration. By default, most systems I know will configure `adduser` or `useradd` to create a usergroup. See `man 8 adduser`:

```
ADDUSER(8)              System Manager's Manual             ADDUSER(8)

NAME
       adduser, addgroup - add a user or group to the system

...

DESCRIPTION
       ...

   Add a normal user
...
       By default, each user in Debian GNU/Linux  is  given  a  corre-
       sponding  group  with  the  same  name.  ...
```

Same holds for the low-level `useradd`:

```
USERADD(8)            System Management Commands            USERADD(8)

NAME
       useradd - create a new user or update default new user
       information
...

DESCRIPTION
       useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,
       administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.

       ...

       By default, a group will also be created for the new user (see
       -g, -N, -U, and USERGROUPS_ENAB).
```

As long as you only use `adduser` and `deluser`, you shouldn't come into a situation where the group already exists.